# Can auto-implemented properties be bound?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-binding

I have a property in a complex object such as this:

```
public string startHour
{
    get
    {
        return StartTime != null ? ((DateTime) StartTime).ToString("%h") : "";
    }
    set { startHour = value; }
}
```

My question is: Can this be bound in a `HiddenFor` to a form, and still post back?
Would look like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.startHour)
```

I'm asking this because I'm using automatic properties in a complex object in my model, and the complex object is returning null, so could this cause a problem?

I've looked up 100+ questions related to my problem, and afaik I'm doing everything right.

Comment: Your property set look like an infinite loop. Even if that wasn't the case, your get would not return the set value which seems weird.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to another site in the Stack Exchange network - i.e.: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well I couldn't find any info related to my question, so if you can provide a direct link to another source with the same question with a proper answer, that would be appreciated.

Comment: @the_lotus returns just fine, should work like a regular { get; set; } just adding a set action to it instead of simply calling it with => which would make it read-only.

Comment: @user3554331 you mean, setting a value in the startHour property works with that code?

Comment: It's what it asks for when going by the MVC standards, the property works fine showing the value, just wondering if binding to POST would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Used private properties for auto-implemented properties, works perfectly now.